# Unused port on Linksys 5 port workgroup hub still blinks even with nothing connected to it

Tags: router, hub, workgroup

The light on port 5 on the Ethernet hub will continue to blink green as long as the power is on. I have removed the power for 30 seconds and inserted the power cable again without any change.

- Model Number: EW5HUB
- Standards: IEEE 802.3
- Ports:

  - One 10BaseT Uplink Port (shared)
  - Five 10BaseT RJ-45 Port
- Topology: Star Speed (Mbps): 10Mbps

Comment: What kind of hub is it? Just mentioning the brand and the number of ports is as specific as a '4 wheeled car from brand X'.

Comment: Without any information (i.e.: model number? Did it _ever_ work right?) its hard for us to say; but it sounds broken.

Comment: Yes, it has worked correctly in the past.Model Number: EW5HUB
Standards: IEEE 802.3
Ports: One 10BaseT Uplink Port (shared)
Five 10BaseT RJ-45 Port
Topology: Star
Speed (Mbps): 10Mbps

Comment: Yes, it has worked correctly in the past. 2 Ports are in use. A 3rd is plugged in for a laptop that is usually in the case - meaning the cable is in the port but not connected to the laptop. Nothing is plugged into port 4 or 5. Port 4 does not blink. Port 5 blinks like 8 or 10 times a second.                      Model Number: EW5HUB
Standards: IEEE 802.3
Ports: One 10BaseT Uplink Port (shared)
Five 10BaseT RJ-45 Port
Topology: Star
Speed (Mbps): 10Mbps

Comment: If you remove the uplink cable from the Hub, does the Port 5 link/activity light turn off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [EWH5 manual](http://ec1.images-amazon.com/media/i3d/01/A/man-migrate/MANUAL000003098.pdf) (page 3), if you use the uplink then port 5 will become inactive. The Port 5 green link/activity blinking is indicating the uplink connection.

[image: hub]

[image: hub manual]

Answer (score 0):

That is because it is a hub. And a hub is just simple networking device where once a packet is sent to one of the ports, it is sent out to all of the other ports.

Take a look [here](http://askleo.com/whats_the_difference_between_a_hub_a_switch_and_a_router/) for more information.